# How to make checkbox selection triggering in sequence while calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 checkboxes and each one holds a flag value and calls the same function. How can i make sure that the selection of these checkboxes makes calls as per the order of checking the check boxes.

Issue : When I click on the check boxes quickly, though i selected checkbox-1 and then checkbox-2 in sequentially, it internally making the first call to checkbox-2 and then it is calling for the chekbox-1 event. Please note this is an intermittent issue which happens only when the user does the checking the boxes very quickly.

Query : Is there any way to make sure the order of checkbox firing?

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: Can you disable other checkboxes until function for first is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any code snippet so I will answer only theoretically. Your problem is common for the non-blocking I/O and the UI, if the user clicks something very fast, for example form submit button, he can send the form many times.

The easiest method to avoid such issue is to block other check-boxes, so when any of request is pending set some Boolean indicator and if this indicator is true then disable other check-boxes, when response comes back unblock the interface and set indicator to false again.